# reading lines into lists with prolog

Tags: list, file, io, prolog

I have a text file with some information, each line is a list of values. I want to read each line and store it in a list with all the other lines.
This is the code I have so far

```
getLines:-
      open('textFile.abc', read, Source),
      readData(Source,DataList),
      write(DataList).

readData(Source,DataList):-
                    read(Source,NewLine),
                    NewLine== end_of_file -> fail;true,
                    readData(Source,[DataList|NewLine]).

readData(Source,[DataList|end_of_file]).
```

this is the text file 'textfile.abc'

```
[0.45,20,850,900,3].
[0.45,20,850,900,2].
[0.45,20,850,900,1].
```

When I run getLines it executes and writes '_G1147068' instead of the list of items.
I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason why your code does not work the way you intend it to is found in the second clause of `readData/2` (quoted below). It contains two singleton variables and `[DataList|end_of_file]` is not a list (since `end_of_file` is an atom).

```
readData(Source,[DataList|end_of_file]).
```

Your code can be improved in other ways as well:

- You open a stream but you never close it: you can use `close/1` for this.
- Even if you close the stream after `readData/2` succeeds, suppose your program throws an exception or fails while running `readData/2`. Now `close/1` will not be reached and the stream will still be open. Luckily, there is `setup_call_cleanup/3` which closes the stream even if your code fails / throws an exception.
- Since the data you are reading happens to be Prolog terms, you can use `read_term/3` which comes with [many nice options](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=read_term/2).
- Notice that in list construction `L = [H|T]` I make sure the `T` is always a list.

Resulting code:

```
getLines(L):-
  setup_call_cleanup(
    open('textFile.abc', read, In),
    readData(In, L),
    close(In)
  ).

readData(In, L):-
  read_term(In, H, []),
  (   H == end_of_file
  ->  L = []
  ;   L = [H|T],
      readData(In,T)
  ).
```

Hope this helps you out!

Comment: thanks, I'm just learning Prolog and it can get really confusing at times. The information you gave is really helpful though, I can already see a few things it can improve in my project.